# Tilting of lens (oscillations)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, geometric-optics, lenses

Please help me solve it or just provide me a good enough hint.
I have a problem with locating the image after the lens is tilted.

> Monochromatic light rays parallel to the $x$-axis strike a convex lens AB. If the lens oscillates such that AB tilts up to a small angle $\theta$ (in radians) on either side of $y$-axis then, the amplitude of oscillations of the image will be?
> [image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine the lens $AB$ with a ray at an angle $\theta$ passing through one of the focal points of the lens $F$ (left hand diagram).

On the other side of the lens there is another focal point at a distance $f$ from the pole $P$ of the lens.

Length $FC = \dfrac{f}{\cos \theta}$

[image]

Now rotate the lens through an angle $\theta$ and have incoming parallel rays hitting the lens.

The new focal point is $F'$ at a distance of $f'$ from the pole of the lens.

Figure $FCF'P$ is a parallelogram and so $FC = PF' = \dfrac{f}{\cos \theta} = f'$

So the focal point of the lens has moved a distance

$f'-f = \dfrac{f}{\cos \theta} - f \approx f(1+\dfrac {\theta^2}{2}) -f = \dfrac{f\theta^2}{2}$ if $\theta$ is small.

Comment: So for small angles the effect is negligible.

Comment: It is a second order effect. For a lens of focal length $150$ mm, a $5^\circ$ rotation moves the focal point by roughly $\frac 1 2$ mm.

Comment: @RAHUL You will note that I never gave an answer to the question all I did was evaluate the distance that the focal point had moved.  To give an amplitude one needs to have a reference position which in a lot of cases one would call the "equilibrium position".  Now in this example one might call the "equilibrium position" the lens when $\theta = 0$ and then the maximum excursion from the "equilibrium position, the amplitude is $\dfrac{f\theta^2}{2}$.  I would liken this to a rectified alternating voltage output where the voltage never reverses polarity.  What do you think?